# Error writing from DictReader into CSV

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, field, writer

I have the following code:

```
def fillBlanks():

    # There are duplicate fields in the 'HEADERS' list. A better 'HEADERS' list might be:
    # HEADERS = ['ST', 'Year', 'PCT_SHORT', 'PCT_V_SHORT']
    HEADERS =['ST','Year','PCT_SHORT','PCT_V_SHORT','Year','PCT_SHORT','PCT_V_SHORT','Year','PCT_SHORT','PCT_V_SHORT' ]
    fileH = open(outputDir+"PCT_SHORT_V_SHORT.csv", 'rb')
    fileb = open(outputDir+"PCT_SHORT_V_SHOR.csv", 'wb')
    reader = csv.DictReader(fileH, HEADERS,restval=0)

    for row in reader:
      print row
```

It outputs, the following:

```
 # The `None` key is the result of the data row having more columns than the 'HEADERS' list has fields.
 {None: ['2012', '36', '12'], 'PCT_SHORT': '19', 'Year': '2013', 'PCT_V_SHORT': '17', 'ST': 'OK'}
 {'PCT_SHORT': 0, 'Year': 0, 'PCT_V_SHORT': 0, 'ST': 'AZ'}
 {None: ['2012', '14', '1'], 'PCT_SHORT': '24', 'Year': '2013', 'PCT_V_SHORT':  '2', 'ST': 'ID'}
```

where 0 fills in fields that were previously missing.

How do I go about writing each row of this out to a CSV. I have been trying to use something along the lines of.

```
with(fileb) as out:
  csv_out=csv.writer(out)

csv_out.writerow(['ST','Year','PCT_SHORT','PCT_V_SHORT','Year','PCT_SHORT','PCT_V_SHORT','Year','PCT_SHORT','PCT_V_SHORT','Year','PCT_SHORT','PCT_V_SHORT'])

for row in reader:
  csvwriters.writerow(row)
```

I get a Error!

```
sequence expected
```

I have also tried to use DictWriter, but I am not familiar with it. I am very new to python. is there anyway to simply write the resulting rows of the DictReader to a new CSV?

Comment: What's the format of the data you want to write to the `csv` file? There are duplicate fields in your `HEADER` which result in the rows with keys of `None`.

Comment: The fields are integers. Perhaps I need to change the duplicate headers? I can do this really quick.

Comment: I went in and changed the headers, I also added headers that were missing. I am still getting the same errors. My main problem in the beginning was that I had fields that were missing I want to fill with 0. hence why I'm using the DictReader.

Comment: You need to ensure the `HEADERS` list has the same number of columns as the data you're reading from `PCT_SHORT_V_SHORT.csv`.

Comment: I did this and it is writing, but not replacing the blank values with 0 as I thought it would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct about the `DictWriter` object.

The [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) object can be used to write from a `dict` to a `csv` file:

```
with(fileb) as csvfile:
    csv_out = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=HEADERS)

    csv_out.writeheader()

    for row in reader:
        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

To replace blank values read in from input:

```
# The names of the fields you want to check
fields = ['ST', 'Year']
# The value you want to replace a blank with. In this case, a 0
marker = 0

for row in reader:
    # Check the values, within this row, for each of the fields listed 
    for field_name in fields:
        field_value = str(row[field_name]).strip()

        row[field_name] = field_value or marker   

csv_out.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I have tried this and I receive another error.                                                Error! sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found

Comment: Error! sequence item 0: expected string, NoneType found

Comment: I deleted a row of bad data from the input file and it now writes, but it is not replacing the blank values. Any idea why this would be. When I print the rows they print correctly.

Comment: You'll need to manually replace the blank values. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This worked for 1 field. Is there a way to do for multiple fields though?

Comment: Yes. You could store the required fields in a list and iterate through them.

Comment: You're welcome. You could accept this answer to help the next person with the same problem.